# What will be a result from var number = "1.2"; console.log(number - 0.2); console.log(number + 0.2);?

Tags: javascript

What will be an output of:

```js
var number = "1.2";
console.log(number - 0.2);
console.log(number + 0.2);
```

And why?

Comment: Is this an interview/quiz question?

Comment: You might be under a misapprehension this is a puzzle site. Execute and find out. Then if you have a question, ask.

Comment: @Amadan: I think we all know what would be the follow-up question :)

Comment: Well, yes. But it's such a low-effort question, someone with 10K rep should know better.

Comment: Related material: https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat

Comment: If you like high effort questions please feel free to look at my other last questions with no answers. Lots of such to find out and i'd really love some feedback there! Ps. Sergio, thanks for the link, nice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer will be
1 and
1.20.2 respectively

Note that number is  string, but since - operator is not supported by string, JS converts it to number thus the output 1. for the second case, since + operator is supported by string, it will simply concatenate it, hence the answer 1.20.2

Answer (score 0):

The output is

1

1.20.2

Why ?

In the first case the variable string is converted to number because there is no `-` operator for strings

But there is a `+` operator for string and it make a concatenation of string, it is in the second case prefered to first convert into number